# Ruby on Rails: How to iterate whether the user already commented on the post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first question here in stackoverflow, so please bear with me hehe.

I have three models: User, Post, and Comments.

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

# post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

# comments.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to let the user comment only once in a post. If there is already an existing comment by the same user, it should not have accept the save/create.

So far, my idea is to create a model function where it iterate all of the exisiting post.comments.each then check all of the users, then if there is, then the comment is invalidated. Though I have no Idea how to do it.

If you have any idea (and perhaps the code snippets), please do share. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `comment.rb`

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:post_id]}
```

This validation will make sure the combination `user_id` and `post_id` will be unique in your `comments` table.

Comment: OMG I didn't know it would be this easy. Thanks!!!! This is a big help for me thank you!!

Comment: can I ask you another one? What if I don't want to let User comment on his own Post? What should I put in the code? TIA!

Comment: @roseann you can ask as many as you like, but you should post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of ways to do it.

Firstly, it is possible to validate uniqueness of user_id - post_id combinations in `comments`:

```
# app/models/comments.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, scope: :account_id
```

Another approach is to manually check for comment existance before creating a comment:

```
if Comment.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: params[:comment][:post_id])
  # render error
else
  Comment.create(params[:comment])
end
```

But in a concurrent environment both approaches may fail. If your application is using a concurrent server like [puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) or [unicorn](https://rubygems.org/gems/unicorn/versions/5.1.0) you will also need a database constraint to prevent creation of duplicated records. The migration will be as follows:

```
add_index :comments, [:user_id, :post_id], unique: true
```

Comment: OMG thank you! Will use the manually check in my controller other than using it in model. I also don't want to let them enter the "new" form so that they can't see it

Comment: can I ask you another one? What if I don't want to let User comment on his own Post? What should I put in the code? TIA!

Comment: On the server side you can check for existence of Post with given post_id and user_id in the same way:
`Post.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:comment][:post_id])`
This is to prevent users from posting comments via curl or similar tool

On the client side in the view I guess you already have @post instance. So you may just hide form if `@post.user_id == current_user.id`